# What is the origin of the shofar sounds?

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

There are 4 major *shofar* sounds, or notes, sounded on *Rosh Hashana*:

- **Tekiah**: A long, continuous blast.
- **Shevarim**: Three short "broken" blasts.
- **Teruah**: A rapid series of nine or more very short blasts.
- **Tekiah Gedolah**: A *tekiah* blast held as long as possible.

What is the Torah source for these specific sounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Torah itself uses only the terms "tekiah" and "teruah" ([Num. 10:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0410.htm#3)ff). Elsewhere ([Lev. 25:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm#9)) the Torah puts the verb *haavir* ("to make pass") before and after references to a teruah, implying that it should be preceded and followed by a long drawn-out sound - which tells us that the basic order is tekiah-teruah-tekiah.

So there's no doubt what a tekiah is. However, the word "teruah" is translated in Aramaic as "yevava," which means a crying sound, and there are three possibilities what this means: moaning (medium-length sounds, what we call "shevarim"); sobbing (short sounds, what we call "teruah"); or both, first moaning and then sobbing. Already in the era of the Mishnah there was uncertainty which of these three is the true "teruah"; accordingly, it was instituted that we do all three.

(Talmud, Rosh Hashanah [33b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1351&size=1)-[34a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1352&size=1); Shulchan Aruch Harav, [Orach Chaim 590:1-2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25075&pgnum=224))

[How this uncertainty came about is itself the subject of dispute. R. Hai Gaon explains that in reality, any of these three would satisfy the Torah obligation of hearing a crying sound, so various communities did it in various ways; the enactment to do all three was in order to unify the various practices. By contrast, Rambam writes ([Shofar 3:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3603.htm#2)) that the true original meaning of "teruah" was actually forgotten, and so we do all three to be on the safe side.]

Returning to tekiah, it can be drawn out as long as you want (Shulchan Aruch Harav, [Orach Chaim 590:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25075&pgnum=225)). So the custom developed to make the last one (of the first set of 30 sounds) extra-long ("tekiah gedolah"), also symbolizing the idea (from [Ps. 47:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2647.htm#6)) that G-d's presence "ascends with the sound of the shofar." But it's not a halachic requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Digging around I found the following [dvar torah by Prof. A. Harel Fisch on Bar-Ilan's website](http://www.biu.ac.il/jh/parasha/eng/rosh/fis.html) regarding a passage from S.Y. Agnon's Days of Awe (Hebrew edition; the English translation is an abridgment) pp. 108-110:

> The first round of blowing the *shofar*, we sound *tekiah-shevarim-teru'ah* and the last *tekiah* is not part of this round, but the Rabbis of blessed Memory enacted that one should sound a *teruah* (succession of tremulous notes), with a simple blast (*tekiah*) before it and a simple blast after it. The first *tekiah* is of the essence, the second, a rabbinic enactment. A *tekiah* is a plain, straight sound, as I have said--the sound that comes out and travels, piercing the air, until it reaches our patriarch Abraham of blessed memory.

Prof. Fisch continues:

> Later Agnon characterizes each of the three sounds of the shofar: "The *tekiah* stands for the totally righteous..." (based on *Midrash Yehi Or* in *Menorat ha-Maor Zohar*, also cf. *Emor* 98). According to this, the plain blast (which precedes the tremulous note) is really essential. This is the simple sound, corresponding to the horn of the wild goat and symbolic of a person whose reasoning is straight and who does not bow over. Next we sound the tremulous note of the person who bends his reason and casts himself down; the latter is symbolized by the curved horn of the ram. These sources cited in Agnon's book support the first *tanna* mentioned in the *Mishnah*, and give preference to the *tekiah*, the simple sound that symbolizes the totally righteous.

If anyone has the book, I'd love to see more.